# Foundation [6.4.3] & jQuery [3.2.1] Reveal Modal not working

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

**Foundation's modal is not working for me in my project.**

I've confirmed Foundation and jQuery are loaded as well as the CSS for the Foundation Modal to work but it's not triggering on click as is.

Interestingly, if you run

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var popup = new Foundation.Reveal($('#videoModal'));
    popup.open();
});
```

In the browser console, the modal appears. So, I feel confident the js and css are available.

I just can't resolve why the click event on the anchor is not firing it as it should. I've followed the advice on this page: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html

My Test Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing Modal from Foundation</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dist/styles/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-top: 200px;" class="video-callout">
      <a data-open="videoModal">
        <h6>Watch the video</h6>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="reveal" id="videoModal" data-reveal>
      <h1>Hey!</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="/assets/dist/scripts/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/dist/scripts/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you see some JavaScript errors (use F12 browser tools)?

Comment: This is the only error I am seeing in console which I 'believe' is related to a Chrome extension. I do not get any errors while running in Safari and the click still doesn't trigger the modal. 

What's bizarre to me is that when I add onclick="foo()" to the anchor tag element and define this function:
`foo = () => {
        console.log('clicked!');
        new Foundation.Reveal($('#videoModal')).open();
      }`

It fires the modal. Obviously, that shouldn't be necessary but it suggests that the data-open attribute isn't doing it's job I guess?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Was left out of the document and that seems to be the main culprit.